# Access window (global variable) in my pug template file

Tags: templates, pug

How can I access `window.abc` in my pug file?

Comment: could you give more details about your pug and related files?

Comment: My window.abc is set in a JS file. I want my HTML to be generated something like this `<div>${window.abc}</div>`

Comment: `window.abc` is set in my config.js which is imported in my pug file